# Merge lodash array nodejs mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, merge, lodash

I want to merge my collection by updating a number field and an array.

This is my schema mongodb :

```
{
   url: String,
   email: [String],     
   vote: Number
}
```

node.js code :

```
like = _.merge(like, req.body);
like.save(function (err) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
});
```

this code updates the vote field by incrementing a value, but replaces the existing email whereas I want to push the email into the array.

I want to increment vote value, and push email into an array, like `["a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com",... ]` etc.

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: If you do a `console.log(req.body)` before the `_.merge()` statement, what's the object logged?

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`_.assign()`**](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) instead which works in a way that for each property in source, it copies its value as-is to destination. If property values themselves are objects, there is no recursive traversal of their properties. Entire object would be taken from source and set in to destination. The following examples demonstrate the differences between [**`_.assign()`**](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) and [**`_.merge()`**](https://lodash.com/docs#merge):

```
var dest = {
  p: { x: 10, y: 20},
};

var src = {
  p: { x: 20, z: 30},
};

console.log(_.merge(dest, src));
```

**Output**

```
[object Object] {
  p: [object Object] {
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    z: 30
  }
}

console.log(_.assign(dest, src));
```

**Output**

```
[object Object] {
  p: [object Object] {
    x: 20,
    z: 30
  }
}
```

So your final code should look like:

```
like = _.assign(like, req.body);
like.save(function (err) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
});
```

Comment: I try with _.assign but, the existant email was replace by the new email instead be push. thanks a lot

Comment: Try [defaults()](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults) - it's like `assign()`, except it doesn't override existing property values.

Answer (score 0):

With mongoose docs you can modify the document like any other object in javascript. Your vote was not getting incremented most likely because `req.body.vote` was the same value as `like.vote`, couldn't know for sure with out knowing the incoming data. But the following solution will increment the vote and `_.merge` the `email` property.

```
// for just modifing the email property
like.email = _.merge(like.email, req.body.email);
// increment the vote like you would with any number in JavaScript
like.vote++;
like.save(function(err) {
   if (err) retuurn handleError(res, err);
   // handle successfull save
 });
```

Comment: It's not Work for me, because, I want to update the vote field by increment, and I want to push an email into the array. thx

Comment: Your question said nothing about incrementing the vote, be clear on what your asking. Ill update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I combined @Nindaff's solution with the push method, this solution worked for me :

```
like.vote = (like.vote, req.body.vote);
like.email.push(req.body.email);
like.save(function (err) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
});
```